# Get Results from Linq query(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery) and convert to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I have a linq query that returns multiple rows from a table and I would like to get count of number of rows and also change the results from System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery to List. strUserID is not the primary key to customer services table.

```
var AllCustomerServices = from service in _context.CustomerServices
    where service.strUserID == Session["userID"].ToString()
    select service;
```

It is throwing exception for following code:

```
if (AllCustomerServices.Count() > 0)
{
    List<CustomerServices> cstSrvs = AllCustomerServices.ToList();
}
```

Exception:

> 'AllCustomerServices.ToList()' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   [NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.]

Comment: Hi there. Can you please provide the full exception stack?

Comment: @JuanR [NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the session value into a variable first:

```
var value = Session["userID"].ToString(); //Watch out for nulls, by the way

var AllCustomerServices = from service in _context.CustomerServices
where service.strUserID == value
select service;
```

The error message suggests that LINQ to Entities is attempting to translate the call to `Session["UserID"]` to something it can execute on the store when in fact, all you need to pass on to the store is the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

It should be work, but I don't understand, why you try List put in another List

```
var AllCustomerServices = _context.CustomerServices.Where(w=>w.strUserID == Session["userID"].ToString()).ToList();

    if (AllCustomerServices.Any())
    {
        List<CustomerServices> cstSrvs = new List<CustomerServices>();
        cstSrvs.AddRange(AllCustomerServices);
    }
```

P.S it's `var AllCustomerServices` already is `List<CustomerServices>`